# Why can not I compare the date that I received from the function parseTimeM,with the sign >=?

Tags: haskell, time, haskell-stack

```
import           Data.Text
import           Data.Time         ( Day, UTCTime, getCurrentTime)
import           Data.Time.Clock
import           Data.Time.Calendar
import           Data.Time.Format    

getDateFromUser :: IO (Either UserError Date)
getDateFromUser = do
Prelude.putStrLn "Пожалуйста, укажите дату для прогноза в формате 
ГГГГ-ММ-ДД:"
date <- Prelude.getLine
let forecastDay = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%m-%d" date :: Maybe Day
    let currentTime = show forecastDay
    if date >= currentTime 
        then return $ Right $ (Data.Text.pack date)
        else return $ Left InvalidDate
```

start

```
~/Weather-report/Weather$ stack exec Weather-exe
Пожалуйста, укажите дату для прогноза в формате ГГГГ-ММ-ДД:
2018-05-31
InvalidDate
```

But when I write like this:
    date <= currentTime ...

```
~/Weather-report/Weather$ stack exec Weather-exe
2018-05-31
Just "2018-05-31"
2018-05-30
Just "2018-05-30" and more
```

Question:  Why does not it work with >=
Why does not it work
Maybe it's because of the function parseTimeM?
Can this function work with dates from the past and from the future there is not?

Comment: You realize that you are always comparing the same day to itself, right? `date >= currentTime` should always be true, because `currentTime` is really just proof that you can parse the user's input.

Comment: Why? Because capital `J` from the `Just` constructor of `Maybe` which is being displayed via `show` is lexicographically greater than the character `2` from `2018`.  In general you probably shouldn't compare dates via strings.  Instead of `Left InvalidDate` try printing the two strings you are comparing and see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Since `forecastDay` is a `Maybe Day` value, you want the string representation of the `Day` value wrapped inside it, not the string representation of the `Just` value. Lexicographically, any string starting with a number is going to be less than a string starting with `J`.

One option is to use `maybe` to apply `show` *or* get a suitable default string value.

```
getDateFromUser :: IO (Either UserError Date)
getDateFromUser = do
Prelude.putStrLn "Пожалуйста, укажите дату для прогноза в формате 
ГГГГ-ММ-ДД:"
date <- Prelude.getLine
let forecastDay = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%m-%d" date :: Maybe Day

    -- Instead of let currentTime = show forecastDay
    let currentTime = maybe "9999-99-99" show forecastDay

    if date >= currentTime 
        then return $ Right (Data.Text.pack date)
        else return $ Left InvalidDate
```

---

Given that `currentTime` should only equal `date` or `9999-99-99`, all you are doing is validating the user's input. You can do that simply with

```
date <- Prelude.getLine
return case parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%m-%d" date :: Maybe Day of
    Just x -> Right (Data.Text.pack x)
    Nothing -> Left InvalidDate
```

Comment: I checked this code.  When I entered 2018-05-32 I got a date back.  But 32 days in a month does not exist and it turns out that the function of parsetTimeM does not work. And if I entered
any text, then I get this text back.

Comment: @AshotBes Could not reproduce. `parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%m-%d" "2018-05-32" :: Maybe Day` produces `Nothing` here.